# Register a view in ArcGIS returns error 999999

Tags: arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, error-999999, sql-view

I have created a view in an enterprise geodatabase (SQL Server) using `arcpy.management.CreateDatabaseView`.

It shows correctly in ArcMap, and now I want to register it properly. I have done this many times without any problem but now I get only a generic 999999 error. Both `arcpy.management.RegisterWithGeodatabase` and the *Register With Geodatabase* toolbox give the same error.

```
Executing: RegisterWithGeodatabase myconnection.sde\my_view OBJECTID Shape POLYGON "PROJCS['RD_New',GEOGCS['GCS_Amersfoort',DATUM['D_Amersfoort',SPHEROID['Bessel_1841',6377397.155,299.1528128]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Double_Stereographic'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',155000.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',463000.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',5.38763888888889],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.9999079],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',52.15616055555555],UNIT['Meter',1.0]];-30515500 -30279500 10000;-100000 10000;-100000 10000;0,001;0,001;0,001;IsHighPrecision" #
Start Time: Tue Oct 31 16:57:17 2023
ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Operation Failed
Failed to execute (RegisterWithGeodatabase).
Failed at Tue Oct 31 16:57:18 2023 (Elapsed Time: 1,01 seconds)
```

The code is:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.management.RegisterWithGeodatabase (
    "myconnection.sde\my_view", 
    "OBJECTID", 
    "Shape",
    "POLYGON", 
    "PROJCS['RD_New',GEOGCS['GCS_Amersfoort',DATUM['D_Amersfoort',SPHEROID['Bessel_1841',6377397.155,299.1528128]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Double_Stereographic'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',155000.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',463000.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',5.38763888888889],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.9999079],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',52.15616055555555],UNIT['Meter',1.0]];-30515500 -30279500 10000;-100000 10000;-100000 10000;0,001;0,001;0,001;IsHighPrecision", 
    "#")
```

I have seen ["Error 999999: Error executing function - Attribute conversion error" when running RegisterWithGeodatabase](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/342954/error-999999-error-executing-function-attribute-conversion-error-when-runni#343076), but it didn't help unfortunately

What else could be going wrong?

The version of ArcMap is 10.8

**Update 1 Nov 2023**
I have managed to reproduce this with a very simple view. I think the following code is self explanatory, but if the question can be reopened, I will add this as an answer.

```
select 
    objectid,
    shape as this_fieldname_is_longer_than_31_characters
from mytable
```

Comment: What parameter values did you use with your ArcPy code when you saw this error?

Comment: @PolyGeo The parameters are on the first line of the code block I included. I'm not sure what else I could add?

Comment: You also used CreateDatabaseView according to the body of your question. I think that should be part of your code snippet so that the community can begin clarifying what in your input data to your workflow may be leading to the error later.

Comment: There’s no information in your question body about software versions being used.

Comment: Okay, I'll add that tomorrow when I'm in the office. But I don't agree with closing the question just because of that.

Comment: Are you meeting the [ArcGIS Desktop 10.8 System Requirements](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/system-requirements/latest/arcgis-desktop-system-requirements.htm) for all parts of your configuration involved in this workflow?  If so, or if not, I think they should mentioned in your question body.

Comment: Yes, I am. Is there anything in particular that could influence the workings of arcpy?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of but since you're getting the 999999 from the tool itself as well as within ArcPy it suggests to me that your data and the view on it may be where attention should be focussed.  We currently know nothing about the SQL data types that you are using and whether any of them may be unsupported.

Comment: Yes, I agree the type of data is important. It's just that I don't really see why *system requirements* (except "Software required to connect to a DBMS") are relevant. It could be, but then *all* questions should provide this information.

Comment: Potentially, all questions should provide this information, but I think ERROR 999999 is a class of question where doing that becomes more important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that `RegisterWithGeodatabase` failed because some of the fields in my view had names longer than 31 characters. [31 is the maximum fieldname length in a SQL Server Enterprise Geodatabase](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/geodatabases/manage-sql-server/enterprise-geodatabase-limits.htm), even though the underlying database supports longer names.

This fails:

```
select 
    objectid,
    shape as this_fieldname_is_longer_than_31_characters
from mytable
```

This works:

```
select 
    objectid,
    shape as this_fieldname_is_shorter
from mytable
```